# select onchange event.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

In my component I want to do some stuff after the select value has changed.

select:

```
<select value={current} onChange={this.onSelectChange.bind(this)}>
    {options}
</select>
```

onchange event:

```
onSelectChange(event) {
    const { cookies } = this.props;

    // event.value is undefinded
}
```

I need the props in the event so I use bind(this). But why is `event.value` undefined (`event.target.value` also)

Comment: I think there is an issue with some other piece of code in the component that uses this select element. If you can put the component code. Otherwise this code is all good and should work.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing some other mistake, check the console.

Check this example `event.target.value` will always have the selected value:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

  onSelectChange(e){
     console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  render(){
     return(
       <select onChange={this.onSelectChange.bind(this)}>
         <option value='1'>1</option>
         <option value='2'>2</option>
         <option value='3'>3</option>
       </select>
     )  
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also use this method.

```
<select value={current} onChange={()=>this.onSelectChange(e)}>
    {options}
</select>.

onSelectChange(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}
```